# how to manage a team to make a site using drupal?

Tags: drupal, cvs

we have a team and want to make a site using drupal.
as i see all the changes will be saved in database. so how we can have a version control?
should we use of a cvs that take care of databases?
if yes, how can i make a db cvs server?
thanks.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should relate to programming (i.e. writing code). For comparative (and ultimately, subjective) discussions on things like version control, check [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use git. As far as the database goes, you're best off using update hooks to capture schema changes in code. If you're using cck you're not going to be able to do that reliably. It's a bummer really.

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_update_N

Comment: don't forget about features and strongarm.

Answer (score 1):

to port views, content type, contexts you can use http://drupal.org/project/features
Devel http://drupal.org/project/devel have tool to make record macros
But realy there is no universal tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize Git for team development work for code.

As far as version controlling a database, you are not going to want to do that. It is a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can move a lot of the stuff that normally goes in the database into the code instead. If you use the strongarm module along with the features module you can save settings, content types views and much more as code and put it into your VCS.